# Linking a variable and a text box in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, textbox

How can I link a variable and a text box in the simplest possible way?

I.e. If the user changes the text box contents the variable changes and if the program changes the variable the text in the text box changes.

N.B. I'm using the swing and awt libraries.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your variable in an [Observable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) wrapper. It will tell the JTextfield about the changes.

add a [DocumentListener](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) to the field.getDocument() to tell your variable that its value should change.

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself doing lots of custom UI/Bean binding, consider [JGoodies Binding](https://binding.dev.java.net/).

Using [Observable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) or a [DocumentListener](http://file///Users/jason/Documents/JavaDocs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) is ok.

For more advanced stuff, you may want to look at  [PropertyEditor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditor.html), [BeanDescriptor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/BeanDescriptor.html), [BeanInfo](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) and [Customizer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/Customizer.html) classes/interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add an [ActionListener](http://file:///Users/jason/Documents/JavaDocs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) to the JTextField to listen to changes.  When it's time to update the field, make changes to the JTextField and be prepared to ignore the events it fires off as a result.

The other option is to edit the field's [Document](http://file:///Users/jason/Documents/JavaDocs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) directly, and add a [DocumentListener](http://file:///Users/jason/Documents/JavaDocs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) to listen for changes.  I find working with Documents to be more complex than needed, however.